# Finding if a quantity is a Lorentz scalar

Tags: special-relativity, invariants

I am new to special relativity, and I am trying to figure out if $\phi(x)=\frac{a \cdot a}{x \cdot x+a \cdot a-x^{0} a^{0}}$ is a Lorentz scalar, where $x$, and $a$ are four-vectors.

Since the dot product of any two four-vectors is a Lorentz scalar I only need to worry about the $x^0a^0$ term (I think), so I rewrote it as $x^0a^0 = x\cdot a + \vec{x}\cdot \vec{a}$ but now I am not sure how to handle the $ \vec{x}\cdot \vec{a}$ term? I am using the $(+,-,-,-)$ convention.

Any help is very much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a scalar. Consider the following transformation:
$X_0=x_1$
$X_1=x_2$
$X_2=x_3$
$X_3=x_0$
So now
$$\frac{a\cdot a}{x\cdot x + a\cdot a- x^0 a^0} \ne \frac{A\cdot A}{X\cdot X + A\cdot A- X^0 A^0} $$

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I was trying to do a Lorentz transformation and then see that the quantity does not remain the same, but did not know how to deal with the $x^0a^0$ term. Is it possible to do it this way?

Comment: It is, but if you see a single coordinate dependent term it is pretty much guaranteed to not be a scalar, just by inspection

Comment: Is it possible to show me how it is done in this case? because I am still new to the subject and would like to see how one deals with such terms. Thanks

Comment: @Simon in natural units we have $x’_0=(x_0-v x_1)\gamma$ and $a’_0=(a_0-v a_1)\gamma$ so clearly $a_0 x_0 \ne a’_0 x’_0$

Comment: I see that clear things up, thanks.